# How to open http://127.0.0.1:8000 inside docker container

Tags: laravel, docker

I Wanted to Add my Laravel project to a docker image, I managed doing so, one problem tho, when i ran `php artisan serve` it it return this `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

My question is how to open this link inside the container

or is there any better way to achieve the same task

Thanks!

Comment: `php artisan serve` is only meant for local development, it should not be used inside Docker containers. You have to run laravel using a webserver like nginx or apache.

Comment: `curl` can be used to access web resources in the container. You will have to shell into the container using `docker exec -it container_name sh`

Comment: you don't need to run artisan serve from inside the container,  what you can do is expose your database ports (form container) to your machine and run artisan serve outside of the container.  Otherwise you can work in a complete docker flow (if on laravel 8+  Laravel Sail does just that) if working below laravel 8 there are docker for laravel packages/projects out there.

Comment: if you must,  you can expose the ports (in a docker compose) like this https://dev.to/pierangelo1982/dockerize-an-existing-laravel-application-with-docker-compose-3l5m

Comment: Thanks guys for responding 
I decided to take @MaartenDev solution and I installed apache, made the configuration but I faced another error: ```Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message``` so anyone can know how I solve it. thanks alot!

Comment: okey I have removed this warning by running this command `docker run --rm -ti -h myapp.mydomain.com my-image` but now how do I access this